# Continue writing iPhone Mail on Mac without the account configured on Mac

Tags: iphone, mail.app, email, quicktime

I have this very restrictive work e-mail account which I cannot add to my Mac (Airwatch), and I tried to write a long email with the iPhone screen shown via QuickTime and a bluetooth keyboard.

Suddenly the mail was available in the Mail app, and I was able to finish writing the mail on my Mac.

I have no idea how I made that happen (Altough I did insert an image into the mail on my phone).

Is this a feature I can activate intentionally ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a feature called [Handoff](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21868)

> ## [OS X El Capitan: Pick up where you left off with Handoff](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21868)
>
> With Handoff, you can start something on one device (Mac, iOS, or Apple
> Watch) and pick it up on another without losing focus on what you’re
> doing. For example, you can start writing an email on your Mac, then
> pick up where you left off in Mail on your iPhone. Or see a location
> in Maps on Apple Watch, then explore the area in more detail in Maps
> on your Mac.
>
> You can use Handoff with many apps—Calendar, Contacts, Keynote, Mail,
> Maps, Messages, Notes, Numbers, Pages, Reminders, and Safari. Some
> third-party apps may also work with Handoff.
>
> [image]
>
> An app's Handoff icon at the left side of the Dock For Handoff to
> work, you must use [supported devices](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mchlbae2b7f0&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=El%20Capitan%20Mac%20Help135555) that are [signed in to
> iCloud](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mh36834&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=El%20Capitan%20Mac%20Help135555) using the same [Apple ID](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mh22612fa790&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=El%20Capitan%20Mac%20Help135555) and on the same Wi-Fi network.
> The devices must be within Bluetooth range of one another (about 33
> feet or 10 meters); make sure Bluetooth is on for your Mac (in System
> Preferences) and iOS devices (in Settings).
>
> **Turn Handoff on or off**   If you don’t see a Handoff option on your device, it doesn’t work with Handoff.
>
> On your Mac: Choose Apple menu > System Preferences, click General,
> then select “Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices”
> (below “Recent items”). To turn it off, deselect the option.
>
> On iPad, iPhone, or iPod touch: Go to Settings > General > Handoff &
> Suggested Apps, then tap to turn on Handoff. To turn it off, tap the
> option.
>
> On Apple Watch: Open the Watch app on iPhone, go to My Watch >
> General, then tap to turn on Enable Handoff. To turn it off, tap the
> option.
>
> **Hand off between devices**   From your Mac to an iOS device: The Handoff icon of the app you’re using on your Mac appears on iPad,
> iPhone, or iPod Touch in the bottom-left corner of the Lock screen.
> Just swipe up to continue working in the app.
>
> You can also double-click the Home button on the device to go to the
> multitasking screen, then swipe right to see the Handoff icon.
>
> From an iOS device or Apple Watch to your Mac: The Handoff icon of the
> app you’re using on your iPad, iPhone, iPod Touch, or Apple Watch
> appears on your Mac at the left end of the Dock (or the top, depending
> on the Dock position). Just click the icon to continue working in the
> app.
>
> You can also press Command-Tab to [quickly switch to the app](https://support.apple.com/kb/index?page=link&apdid=mchlp2469&viewlocale=en_US&bookId=El%20Capitan%20Mac%20Help135555) that
> has the Handoff icon.